# Crystal Reports in VB6 shows up empty for first run

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

So I'm having a problem with Crystal Reports where the first time I try to run the report, the report shows up empty.  The report shows up with the various separators, lines, boxes, etc., but no data to fill in the report.  I'm using Visual Basic 6 for the coding.  I'm using a lot of inherited code and the code that handles the actual Crystal Reports is a file that is used for other reports and it works fine.  So I'm sure the problem is from what I've done where I'm messing something up.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strRptFilePathTemp As String
Dim strRptFileName As String
Dim cSql As String

cSql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"

Set rs = DbConn.runStatement(cSql, "rs call", , , , , , , , , , True)  'gets a recordset based on the sql statement above

On Error GoTo ErrHandler


strRptFileName = "ReportName.rpt"

strRptFilePathTemp = App.Path


Screen.MousePointer = vbHourglass

Set frmcrystalreport.ReportRS = rs

DoEvents


frmcrystalreport.reportfile = strRptFilePathTemp & strRptFileName
frmcrystalreport.ReportTitle = _
frmCrystalReportsMainForm.GetRptTitle1("ReportTitle, ") & vbCrLf
gblStrReportFileNameLastRun = frmcrystalreport.reportfile
Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

DoEvents

frmcrystalreport.Show vbModal

If Not frmcrystalreport.ReportRS Is Nothing Then
frmcrystalreport.ReportRS.Close
Set frmcrystalreport.ReportRS = Nothing
End If
Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

I've tried playing around with the DoEvents function to see if that can help but haven't had much luck with it.  Everything works fine after that initial failed attempt at running the report.  As long as I don't exit the program, it will print out a report with the valid data once I get passed that blank report.  Thanks for any help you guys can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the problem after stumbling upon something in Crystal Reports.  I had to turn off the save data with report feature in the report file under the File menu.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it has been a while since I used VB6 and CR but I sort of remember that your need to  discard the saved data before setting the viewers report source

```
Report.DiscardSavedData
CRViewer1.ReportSource = Report
```